# Union of Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found a theorem that goes like this..

If $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of a group $G$, and either one of them is a normal subgroup, then $A \cup B=AB.$

Would like to ask if it holds for more subgroups of G, say $A_i$ are all normal subgroups of G, can I say that $\cup A_i = \prod Ai$?

Comment: This "theorem" is false. Consider the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ generated by $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. These are both normal, and their composite is the whole group, but their union is not even a subgroup.

Comment: There are a few  authors, such as Marshall Hall, who define $A \cup B$ to be the subgroup generated by $A$ and $B$, so perhaps that is the definition being used here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $A\cup B$ stands for $\langle A,B\rangle$, the subgroup generated by $A,B$, then what you say is true and it is rather obvious. As you wrote, $\langle A,B\rangle=AB$ $(*)$. Adding another term, $C$ would mean to take $\langle A,B,C\rangle$. This can be written as
$\langle\langle A,B\rangle, C\rangle$ which, by $(*)$ is
$$ \langle\langle A,B\rangle, C\rangle= \langle AB, C\rangle=ABC$$
Induction yields your result.